# Pandas: Conditional column creating

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I'm trying to **create column C**, based on the values in columns A and B given the following conditions:

```
if A < 5000: C = A * B
else: C = A
```

The following gives a syntax error:

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x (x['A'] * x['B)'] if x['A'] < 5000 else x = x['A']),axis=1)
```

How far off am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use vectorized [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['A'] < 5000, df['A'] * df['B'], df['A'])
```

**Performance**:

```
np.random.seed(2019)

N = 1000
data = np.asarray([np.random.rand(N).tolist(), list(range(N))]).T
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B'])

In [56]: %timeit df['C'] = np.where(df['A'] < 5000, df['A'] * df['B'], df['A'])
536 µs ± 47.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [57]: %timeit df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.A * x.B if x.A > 0.5 else x.A, 1)
30.9 ms ± 597 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

```
N = 100000
data = np.asarray([np.random.rand(N).tolist(), list(range(N))]).T
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B'])

In [59]: %timeit df['C'] = np.where(df['A'] < 5000, df['A'] * df['B'], df['A'])
1.29 ms ± 23.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [60]: %timeit df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.A * x.B if x.A > 0.5 else x.A, 1)
3.32 s ± 374 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: .where is definitely more efficient than applying lambda. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, that's indeed a big difference in performance. Wasn't aware that it's *that* slow.

Comment: @displayname - ya, problem is `apply` are loops under the hood.

Comment: @jezrael I see - thanks for the info. Will consider that in the future :) So whenever I can avoid `apply` I should avoid it I guess.

Comment: @displayname - It depends, if exist some vectorized alternative better is avoid, if not exist need it or some another loop solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd want something like

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.A * x.B if x.A > 0.5 else x.A, 1)
```

Complete example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 10
data = np.asarray([np.random.rand(N).tolist(), list(range(N))]).T
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B'])

df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.A * x.B if x.A > 0.5 else x.A, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks! So my error basically boiled down to an equal sign, haha!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the solutions provided before this one are better but I solved it a third way. The dataset is rather small so it'll do for now.

multiply = df['A'] * df['B']
df['C'] = multiply.where(df['A'] < 5000, other=df['A'])